# Distribution of random variables: extracting a blue ball after we have already extracted yellow and green one

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Problem: In an urn there are A yellow, B green and C blue ball. In each round we extract one ball and then place it back into the urn. We extract the balls until we extract a blue one, after we have already extracted at least one yellow and one green ball. What is the distribution of random variables X(number of blue balls that have been extracted) and Y(number of all extractions)?

I was thinking to start with a problem until we extract balls of all colors and then divide it into a problem where the last ball is blue and where the last ball isn't blue.
I don't know how to go about it. Should I go for a different approach?

Comment: Hello @Vicky, I guess that you should try out small values of A, B and C, and try and find a pattern, after around 5 or 6 cases. I am not really great at probability, but I hope this helps!

Comment: There should be no problem computing $P(X=i)$ or $P(Y=j)$ for small $i, j$.  Start there.  As another suggestion, compute $E[X], E[Y]$.  That's a lot easier than computing the exact distribution.

Comment: Split the problem into three parts: (a) expected time to the first yellow or green ball; (b) if that was yellow then further expected time to first green ball, while if it was green then further expected time to first yellow ball; (c) once you have seen yellow and green, further expected time until the next blue ball.  Then combine these results